# How to log apex classes?

Tags: apex, debugging, logging

I'm creating debug log entries for an Apex class I want to watch. When I create it it doesn't show in the debug log entries list, but if I try to create another one for the same class, I get an error saying there already is an entry for that class.

I'm not gonna be running the tests that I want to watch, nor a user. Just a public Visualforce will be tested by an user and its controller is what's going to, indirectly, call the actual class I want to watch.

How could I create a log or what should I do to get a log where all the calls to any method in a class are registered? (or something like it).

Comment: Dan Appleman's Advanced Apex book 3rd edition has a logging framework to consider.

Comment: What do you require that the platform's facilities described in e.g. [Set Up Debug Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&language=en_US) don't allow? Or is that that you are having problems with?